# Running xUnit from within .NET 6 console app

Tags: .net-6.0, xunit, runner

I want to launch an aUnit 2.4.2 test from within a top level .NET 6 program and have added the `xunit.runner.console` v2.4.2 package to my project.

However, when I add this code:

```
var testAssembly = typeof(MyTestClass).Assembly;
var testResults = new Xunit.Runner.Console.Runner().RunAssembly(testAssembly);
```

VS Code complains that `Xunit.Runner` is not available.

How do I invoke the xUnit runner from within my own code?